# Could GPU accelerate gcc/g++ compilation

Tags: gcc, compilation, g++, gpu

When I'm building my gentoo system, my nvidia gpu is usually unused, can I make some use of it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you cannot.

GPUs are typically best at accelerating massively parallel math-heavy tasks that involve little branching. Compiling software is basically the exact opposite of this - it's branch-heavy and does not parallelize well beyond the file level.

Comment: Well, but file level is still a good level. The same that `make -j16` run 16 cores in parallel, could a GPU run my 4000 cores for compilation of 16k source files?

Comment: @AdrianMaire No. They're GPU cores, not CPU cores; they're not architected to run that kind of program. They'd be very slow at it, if they're able to do the job at all. (Which they might not; the size of the compiler as a program is likely larger than a GPU can handle at all.)